# Facebook SDK instruction not making sense about app id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have taken a picture of the Facebook instruction below. What is wrong with it? My app keeps crashing with exception concerning ApplicationId should not be null. But I have added my app id as `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>` in the manifest; that is after adding it as a string in the `strings.xml` resource as `<string name="facebook_app_id">0000000000</string>`

So I figure the instructions is wrong because it does not say which `uses-permission` to add and it says to call the string resource key `com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId` with value `Facebook_app_id`. Here is the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#eclipse

[image]

Comment: Can you post your manifest file? You need to add the `meta-data` element under the `application` element (as shown in your screenshot), and not under any `uses-permission` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply

1.) Create app on Facebook, get the app_id that you will subsequently use to attach to your app.

2.) Define your applicationId in the AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

under `<application android:label="@string/app_name"....` tag
where `app_id` is a string within your strings.xml.

Example (Facebook Sample application):

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            >
        <activity android:name=".HelloFacebookSampleActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>
```

Note the value added under the `<application>` tag
and in strings.xml (MAKE SURE TO DO THIS)

```
<string name="app_id">xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

3.) Set permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is an android requirement, so the app can access the internet.

So with permissions the above manifest will look like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                     android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                >
            <activity android:name=".HelloFacebookSampleActivity"
                      android:label="@string/app_name"
                      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                      android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And here is how I solved it — I think. At least after doing these things, the problem went away.

in strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
….
<string name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId">facebook_app_id</string>
<string name="facebook_app_id">111111111</string>
….
</resources>
```

in manifest

```
<application
… >

<meta-data
  android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
  android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Notice there are two entries in the `strings.xml` file.

Comment: You did what the instruction said, and you did it better than I did. But apparently the first `strings.xml` line is not necessary. So it must be an error on the part of Facebook's writers.